# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'?

Tags: python, discord.py

The code is below

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(Member: discord.member):
    # Welcome message I guess
    channel = discord.utils.get(Member.guild.channels, name='☭│chat')
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="A new member has joined the server :grin:",
        description=f"Thanks for joining {Member.mention} \n Hope you brought pizza!!",
    )
    embed.set_image(url=Member.avatar_url)
    try:
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
    finally:
        await channel.send(":skull:")
```

The error is described in the title, the welcome message really never seems to work because the channel is apparently a "None" object, is the issue the channel declaration?

Comment: `discord.utils.get` isn't able to find the channel you're looking for.

Comment: @Barmar Wait so what else can I use besides discord.utils.get?

Comment: Why do you think you should use something else? Just check if it found the channel before trying to write to it. Maybe the problem is that the channel name is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the `discordpy` module.
According to its [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get), the `discord.utils.get()` function will return `None` if "nothing is found that matches the attributes passed".

This is occouring in your code, and so the later `channel.send()` fails.  To solve this, consider adding an `except AttributeError as e` clause to your (conveniently placed) try-finally statement, and within it check if the type of `channel` is None.

```py
try:
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
except AttributeError as e:
    if channel is None: # None is a singleton (unique) object, so all none instances satisfy this 'is' expression.
        ... you can now know that no channel could be attained
```

@Barmar correctly said that the `finally` statement will be executed even after the exception is caught (and so an error will still occour). This can be circumvented by encapsulating the contents of the `finally` cause in another `try-except` clause pair [though this is somewhat unattractive].

Comment: `finally:` executes even if an exception happens.

Comment: usually we just write `if channel is None`

Comment: @Barmar Good point, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, the issue came up because the owner of that server changed the name of the channel and I've been here confused for over a week on why it didn't work. I really appreciate the help man

Comment: Why not just put `if channel is not None:` around all the code that uses it?

Comment: Note that this will just hide the error, it won't solve the root cause of trying to find the wrong channel name.

Comment: I've modified the answer somewhat, so I'd reccomend reloading the page.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, though I believe the problem in finding the channel is almost certainly not contained within this code. Perhaps the `'☭│chat'` fails. The [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get) doesnt appear to specify whether utf characters are supported (though I'd hope they would be, seeing as Discord allows for them to be used).

Comment: The OP says "the owner of that server changed the name of the channel". I assume that's the problem.

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct. Apologies - I didn't see it.